# How to display Rails-like output from a Rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I have a rake task that is used to set up a bunch of symlinks, but only if they don't already exist. Currently when you run the task, there is no output. So you don't know if anything happened. How can I provide output like Rails generators do by saying 'created' or 'skipped' for each of the symlinks? What gems or modules do i need to include to get this type of functionality?

```
# example
task :setup do
  if !File.symlink?('/example/link')
    %x{cd /example && ln -s /something link}
  end
end
```

Comment: have a look at this question & answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246141/puts-vs-logger-in-rails-rake-tasks

Comment: @Béla that one is talking about using the Rails logger. Not exactly what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use Ruby's [FileUtils ln_s](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-ln_s) functionality for this.

```
ln_s(old, new, options = {})
```

> Creates a symbolic link new which points to old. If new already exists
>   and it is a directory, creates a symbolic link new/old. If new already
>   exists and it is not a directory, raises Errno::EEXIST. But if :force
>   option is set, overwrite new.

```
FileUtils.ln_s '/usr/bin/ruby', '/usr/local/bin/ruby'
FileUtils.ln_s 'verylongsourcefilename.c', 'c', :force => true
```

...

```
ln_s(list, destdir, options = {})
```

> Creates several symbolic links in a directory, with each one pointing
>   to the item in list. If destdir is not a directory, raises
>   Errno::ENOTDIR.
>
> If destdir is not a directory, raises Errno::ENOTDIR.

Comment: So what does `FileUtils.ln_s` provide that `%x{ln -s}` does not?

Comment: @Andrew You don't have to worry about reading input and parsing it from the system call. You can rescue from the Errno::EEXIST exception and handle those cases when the file already exists. Also, %x{} is like doing eval() on the system, it's a bad habit to get into, especially when you can do it in Ruby.

Comment: Okay, sounds like a good idea to switch to that. Now back to my original question, do you know how to create some formatted output similar to that of a Rails generator?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a rails generator? You could also use one of the thor generators. http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2009/07/creating-your-own-generators-with-thor/